# to decode accented letters in the url with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, urldecode

Hello guys i have this form:

```
<form action='file:///C:/Users/amministratore/Desktop/google_cse/ricerca.html' method="get" target='_blank' id='cse-search-box'>
    <input type='text' name='q' size='35' />            
    <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
</form>
```

e this code js:

```
var linkcodificato= self.location.href;
var link= decodeURIComponent(linkcodificato);
```

I can decode many characters (? |! And many others) but not the accented letters ... why?

```
à = %E0
```

**EDIT**

In my search bar i search:

"hello à"

the url that i have is this:

```
?q=Hello+%E0
```

Comment: Accented letters are allowed in a `url`. Or do you mean you have a `url` that has %E0 in it? Can you be more specific with your example?

Comment: @trincot see edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `%E0` represents the `á` character in `ANSI` (`Windows-1252`) encoding, while it is invalid in `utf-8`.

You can avoid this behaviour by making sure that:

- Your `html` file is saved in `utf-8` encoding. How to do this, depends on your editor, but you should look for character encoding options in "Save As", or "Preferences".
- You specify the `utf-8` encoding in your `html` file itself, for example by putting `<meta charset="utf-8">` in the `head` part.
- If with the above two steps it still does not work, you can force the `form` to submit the data in `utf-8` encoding by adding the attribute `accept-charset="UTF-8"` to the `form` tag.

With this set-up you'll find that the `á` character just stays as-is in the `url`. However, the `location.href` will still be encoded, but if you did the above, the encoding will now have `%C3%A0` instead of the offending `%E0`, and that will nicely convert to `à` when you use `decodeURIComponent`.

Whenever you make changes, make sure to refresh the original page, and to resubmit the form.

Here is a suggested start of your `html` code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
```

With the above you ensure that your document runs in `utf-8` mode.

Comment: maybe i must add something to "input" form ?

Comment: Make sure to refresh the page, and submit again. If it still puts `%E0` in the `url` then try the 3rd action I have added in my answer: add an attribute to your `form` tag. Always refresh the page to test any changes, and then submit again.

Comment: now with 3° step works, but why if i alert the url of page "self.location.href" is not encoding in utf-8 ? is there a way to solve it?

Comment: If the encoding you see in `alert` still has `%E0` then it means your `html` is not running as `utf-8`. Please review the start of your `html` document completely, to make sure it is according to the rules for `utf-8`. See my extended answer. When you have done it well, the alert should show `%C3%A0`, which `decodeURIComponent` will replace.